# What does "1" mean in vocabulary entries?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, dictionary

On p24 in Keller's Learn to Read Latin:

> ambulo, ambulire, ambulivi, amhulitum (1-intr.) walk

> amo, amare, amavi, amatus (1-tr.) love

> cogito (1-tr.) think; ponder

> do, dare, dedi, datus give, grant

What does "1" mean in the first three entries of the vocabulary?

Is transitive or intransitive always specified for each verb? Why is it not in the last entry?

Comment: That first entry should read "ambulo, ambulare, ambulavi, ambulatum".

Comment: If your question is solved, don't forget to click on the check mark to indicate it as such.

Answer (score 6):

The number means that the verbs belong to the first conjugation.
There are four or so conjugations or inflection types of Latin verbs.

The verb *dare* is close to the first conjugation but somewhat irregular, which is probably why it has no number.

Conventions like this vary between different dictionaries and textbooks.
Some will mark the declension and transitivity differently, some will not mark them at all.